# Can an Android (Java not C/C++) plugin alter unity textures?

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to use an Android plugin to get around the fact that Unity does not support Video Textures on mobile. I do this by getting the texture ID of the texture that will be used for video (supplied by `Texture2D.GetNativeTextureID()`) which i then pass into the Java Plugin.

The plugin then follows a standard MediaPlayer implementation to play the video into a Surface Texture, which has been assigned the aforementioned texture ID.

When i call the `MediaPlayer.Start()` method, LogCat outputs as if the media player is working normally/as hoped, however the texture never changes in the app. I'm calling the plugin (and even initializing it) from the `OnPreRender()` method of a monobehaviour script, along with making sure to call `GL.InvalidateState()` too.

Here's a look at the relevant code:

Constructor:

```
public VideoPlayer(String _path, Context _cont) {
    m_MediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(_path);
        m_MediaPlayer.setDataSource(_cont, uri);
        m_MediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error setting data source: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Surface Texture Prep:

```
public void PrepareVideo(int _texPtr) {
    try {
        m_SurfTex = new SurfaceTexture(_texPtr);
        m_SurfTex.setOnFrameAvailableListener(this);
        Log.i(TAG, "Surface Texture ready");
        Surface surface = new Surface(m_SurfTex);
        m_MediaPlayer.setSurface(surface);
        Log.i(TAG, "Surface Ready");
        surface.release();
        m_Ready = true;
        m_MediaPlayer.prepare();
    }
    catch (IOException | IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error preparing player: " + e.getMessage());
        m_Ready = false;
    }
}
```

I'd like to know if this type of process is possible with my current setup, or will have to look into writing something using the NDK instead? Specifically, can a surface texture alter a texture produced in Unity?

Comment: not sure you can do this from Java. For sure from a C++ plugin you can use native texture ptr, as shown in the relative example in the doc: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NativePluginInterface.html

Comment: Yea it seems to be the case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appears that while i have found nothing explicitly states that this CAN be done, there is no real information or any examples of it having been done before.

I'll be attempting a re-working of this in native C++ code.

Comment: Mind sharing your solution then? Even today, the new unity VideoPlayer in android is still buggy. The prepare function freezes the app. I am here looking to implement this.

Comment: thanks. I ended up buying easy movie texture to deal with android side of things. amazing that a third party can implement the video correctly but unity can't.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try creating the surfacetexture in the unity rendering thread, for example by overriding runglthreadsjobs in an extended UnityPlayer? That would make sure it bound to the correct glcontext AFAIK.

I have tried sharing contexts, but couldn't get it to work as documentation is sparse and unity is pretty closed down.

In unity 4.2 its a lot easier apparently.

Comment: I attempted something similar to that with no luck, though I didn't do it by overriding runglthreadsjobs, and instead initialized the texture in the `OnPreRender()` call on the main camera of the scene iirc.
I'm not working on the project anymore and unfortunately I don't know if that ever worked, as I moved my focus elsewhere in the app after a bunch of strife with that issue. But thank you for the answer!

Comment: I actually did get it to work later. I shared opengl contexts and passed the Unity native texture ID to Android with a JavaObject call. You have to catch (in runGLThreadsJobs) and pass the Unity context as the subcontext (IIRC). It works pretty well, but I have not tried on many phones. Context sharing is iffy sometimes and it's not done a lot, but as long as both contexts are in the same app there is a good chance it will work well. Other way around (to Unity) is a lot harder since you don't get the chance to pass a subcontext to Unity.

Comment: @RobotRock how do you do that in practice? I can't understand how to "catch" the context from RunGLThreadsJobs. Actually I can't even find RunGLThreadsJobs, all I can find is executeGLThreadJobs, did you mean this one? Right now I'm creating the texture in the java plugin (GLES20.glGenTextures) and passing the texture ID to unity with a sendmessage. Unity then uses the ID to create an external texture (Texture2D.CreateExternalTexture), but it doesn't seem to work. I'm getting "bindTextureImage: clearing GL error: 0x502" and nothing is being displayed. Could you share some piece of code maybe?

Comment: Yeah, I meant that one. I opensourced my project recently that does it: https://github.com/Kjos/HoloKilo Have at it :)