# Can an Android create SurfaceTexture based on Unity Texture2D?

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, stream, surface

My question is related to: [Can an Android (Java not C/C++) plugin alter unity textures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30806718/can-an-android-java-not-c-c-plugin-alter-unity-textures). It seems like this guy was bothering with the same question as myself. I've created plugin which allows to launch stream on Android devices, but I couldn't manage how to show video frames on the Unity interface element (MeshRenderer, RawImage).

My Unity code:

```
private void InitAndroidStreamerObject()
    {
        androidStreamerObj = new AndroidJavaObject("makeitbetter.figazzz.com.vitamiousing7.AndroidStreamer");
        int androidInt = androidStreamerObj.Call<int>("AndroidInt");

        Debug.Log("androidInt = " + androidInt);
    }

    public void StartStream()
    {
        //"http://dlqncdn.miaopai.com/stream/MVaux41A4lkuWloBbGUGaQ__.mp4"; //"rtmp://live.hkstv.hk.lxdns.com/live/hks";
        string streamLink = "rtmp://live.hkstv.hk.lxdns.com/live/hks";

        System.IntPtr ptr = _inputTexture.GetNativeTexturePtr();
        Debug.Log("ptr on Unity side = " + ptr.ToInt32());
        androidStreamerObj.Call("LaunchStream", streamLink, ptr.ToInt32());
    }
```

As you can see, I initialize Android object, get native texture pointer to the texture and send it to the Android plugin.

In Android plugin next things happen:

```
public void LaunchStream(String streamLink, int unityTextureID) {
        final int texId = unityTextureID;
        final String path = streamLink; 
        Log.i("Unity", "hop hop1 = " + path + " textureId = " + unityTextureID);

        _currActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                //_streamConnection = new VideoView(_currActivity); //(VideoView) findViewById(R.id.stream_window);
                //_currActivity.addContentView(_streamConnection, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(1, 1));

                _streamConnection.setVideoPath(path);
                _streamConnection.setMediaController(new MediaController(_currActivity));
                _streamConnection.requestFocus();

                _streamConnection.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                        Log.i("Unity", "some error, I don't know. what = " + what + " extra = " + extra);
                        return false;
                    }
                });

                _streamConnection.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        mediaPlayer.setPlaybackSpeed(1.0f);
                    }
                });

                SurfaceTexture unityTexture = new SurfaceTexture(texId);
                if(unityTexture == null)
                    Log.d("Unity", "unityTexture NULL");
                else
                    Log.d("Unity", "unityTexture is ok");

                _cachedSurface = new Surface(unityTexture);
                if(_cachedSurface == null)
                    Log.d("Unity", "cachedSurface NULL");
                else
                    Log.d("Unity", "cachedSurface is ok");

                _streamConnection.setSurfaceToPlayer(_cachedSurface);
                }
        });
    }
```

You might say that this part of code:

```
SurfaceTexture unityTexture = new SurfaceTexture(texId);
                if(unityTexture == null)
                    Log.d("Unity", "unityTexture NULL");
                else
                    Log.d("Unity", "unityTexture is ok");

                _cachedSurface = new Surface(unityTexture);
                if(_cachedSurface == null)
                    Log.d("Unity", "cachedSurface NULL");
                else
                    Log.d("Unity", "cachedSurface is ok");

                _streamConnection.setSurfaceToPlayer(_cachedSurface);
```

won't work. But it's working absolutely fine, I tried to change the Surface and it was ok. But it's not if I try to do the same from the Unity system.
I understand that I can do what I need to do through Low-Level Native Plugin Interface. But so far I didn't get how I can use it with my Android plugin. Searching for some tutorials I found nothing. I would be really appreciate if somebody could explain me what should I do. Thank you

Comment: any luck with that?

Comment: Hello, @gilgil28, I've done this task with Unity Render Native Plugin. You can find me on Linkedin and I'll try to help you out

Comment: can you help please?